# Google Cloud Kubernetes node stuck in NotReady

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Google Cloud Kubernetes sole node is stuck in:

> NotReady for unknown reasons

Over the last 24 hours the status has not changed. What could be a reason for this?

Available information:

`kubectl get nodes` - node status NotReady

gcloud compute ssh for node - infinite connection

`kubectl describe node`:

**kubectl_describe_node_img_1**

[image: kubectl_describe_node_img_1]

**kubectl_describe_node_img_2**
[image: kubectl_describe_node_img_2]

**Monitoring for node:**

[image: monitoring_for_node_img]

Available ram: 15Gb
Max usage ram: 10Gb
Compute engine -> instance VM -> view logs: says nothing about the problem.

Comment: Have you tried turning that node off then back up? There isn't much info here, all we know is that Kubelet stopped reporting. As a wild guess, that node is frozen somehow. Not knowing much about GKE/GCE, maybe you'ld be able to connect on that nodes console, there could be some additional explanation?

Comment: Nodes rely on comminunication with the master api, via kubelet, to inform its status. This state indicates that the node is not communicating that information. As other said in the comments, there is not enough information other than "*this node lost connectivity*", which can be caused by a large number of reasons. Usually these issues aren't caused by configurations, so I'd suggest to reach out to the [GKE support team](https://cloud.google.com/support/?hl=bg#support-plans) since that's a managed solution and ServerFault is not a site well suited for this kind of specific troubleshooting.